# Flutter LinearProgressIndicator is not loading

Tags: flutter, dart

LinearProgressIndicator is not showing well.It suddenly changes

```
//in the outside of the function
String _progress = "0.0";


//in the build context
Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Download',
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: double.parse(_progress) * 1.00,
                    valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

It draws blue line then turns suddenly red line

[image: Download rate]

Beginnig
[image: Blue line]

Ending
[image: Red line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your initial **_progress = "0.0"** that should work.

**EDIT:**

```
String _progress = "-";

void _onReceiveProgress(int received, int total) {
if (total != -1) {
  setState(() {
    _progress = (received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0);
  });
}
}

//In body build
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Downloading:',
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 20,
            value: double.parse(_progress) * 1.00,
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
```

This should work

Comment: Once work fine, when starts downloading it gives same error

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the potentially working version of your code.

Comment: The edit should work, if it doesn't just, check your variable values. And if still it doesn't work I have another way to do it but might include changing your implementation or just might not work with your implementation.

Comment: It is happening because of the percent character, it is not able to parse the string to double. For once just remove the percent sign from everywhere and try to run it.

Comment: Also change the if condition to   if( 0 <= total && total <= 100) else it'll never stop setting the state.

Comment: Yes we get some succes.now it show but only when it finished.It suddenly draws circle

Comment: That shouldn't happen. What widget are you using? It it a image, if yes then we can try using a loadingBuilder function.

Comment: Also for once just print out the received and total values.

Comment: Yes accually we can try any other like linear or something

Comment: Is it image data or is it something else?

Comment: It is pdf file, linear looks same. it show from start to end in blue color then suddenly it changes to the red and it downloaded

Comment: okay. Just print out the received and total values. There might be a issue with that maybe. because I don't think it should go from 0 to 100 directly.

Comment: Yes I could and I add, it still same

Comment: The code seems right, this should work fine. Are you trying out on an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: Yes I tryed some packages default one is not worked for me and now its working.Thank you all

Comment: Good to know..✌

Answer (score 0):

use `tryParse` because you're trying to parse `'-'` the first time.

```
(double.tryParse(_progress) ?? 0.0) *0.00
```

Edit:

`_progress = (received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";` This will return a string with a % sign in it. That will never parse.

Why not change `_progress` to a `double` and format it to a string where you need it to be a string?

Comment: @nodermonch `_progress = (received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";` This will return a string with a `%` sign in it. That will never parse

Comment: @nodermonch why not change `_progress` to a double and format it to a string where you need it to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because you try `double.parse` string "-". "-" cannot be parsed.

If conditional `(total != -1)` is `true` this again won't work - because "%" cannot be parsed.

You must change value in variable, to be without character "-" or "%" and any character isn't word.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want a `String` data type. 
You can just modify your code like this.

```
 double _progress = 0.0;

  void _onReceiveProgress(int received, int total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      setState(() {
        _progress = (received / total) * 100;
      });
    }
  }

//In body build
Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Downloading:',
              ),
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 20,
                value: _progress,
              ),
             
            ],
          ),
```